# Responsive menu doesn't work with media queries

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, response

I have a responsive menu on my website. Now I'm trying to make responsive also the others parts of the website with media queries.

I added this 2 media queries but after that, the responsive menu doesn't work anymore and I don't know why.

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px)

@media (max-width: 767px)

This is the code for the menu:

CSS

```
.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /*overflow help you to create a new row below because you used float left*/
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.topnav a {

    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    display: block; /*"li a" is an inline element by default so we have to convert it in block element for modify the layout*/
    color: #0099cc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.topnav .active {
    background-color: #f29323;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


.topnav a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #f29323;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a {
      display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
      position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    padding: 0 0;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a <?php echo ($page == "information") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="/nutickets2/index.php">INFORMATION</a>
    <a <?php echo ($page == "report") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="/nutickets2/report.php">Tickets</a>
    <a href="">Info</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
    <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
    </script>
```

This is the code that I added for making the site responsive:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {

.text-head-div div {
    display: block;
}

.text-head-div span {
    display: block;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

.text-head-div div {
    display: block;
}

.text-head-div span {
    display: block;
}
}
```

After that, the responsive menu doesn't work anymore.

If I delete the last code the responsive menu restar to works.

Comment: Where is this class in HTML `text-head-div`? and Please explain the question properly.

Comment: Where is your `text-head-div` element in html?

Answer (score 0):

What does the `text-head-div` element look like? Does it or its children have any fixed width elements?

Code embedded in HTML snippet for easy testing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <style type="text/css">
       .topnav {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden; /*overflow help you to create a new row below because you used float left*/
          background-color: #f6f6f6;
          border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
       }

       .topnav a {

          float: left;
          border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
          display: block; /*"li a" is an inline element by default so we have to convert it in block element for modify the layout*/
          color: #0099cc;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 22px;
          text-decoration: none;
       }


       .topnav .active {
          background-color: #f29323;
          color: #ffffff;
       }

       .topnav a:hover {
          text-decoration: none;
       }


       .topnav a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #f29323;
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
       }

       .topnav .icon {
        display: none;
       }

       @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .topnav a {
            display: none;
        }
        .topnav a.icon {
          float: right;
          display: block;
        }
       }


       @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .topnav.responsive {
            position: relative;
        }
        .topnav.responsive .icon {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
        }
        .topnav.responsive a {
          float: none;
          display: block;
          text-align: left;
        }

       }

       @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .topnav {
          padding: 0 0;
        }
       }

       @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {

       .text-head-div div {
          display: block;
       }

       .text-head-div span {
          display: block;
       }
       }

       @media (max-width: 767px) {

       .text-head-div div {
          display: block;
       }

       .text-head-div span {
          display: block;
       }
       }
 </style>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="/nutickets2/index.php">INFORMATION</a> 
  <a class="active" href="/nutickets2/report.php">Tickets</a> 
  <a href="">Info</a> 
  <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size:15px;">&#9776;</a>
 </div>
 <script>
       function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
          if (x.className === "topnav") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "topnav";
          }
       }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```